# Ftp server on azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I'm want to build a FTP server on Microsoft Azure platform.

The server probably will be based on vsftpd (linux ubuntu server) - not closed. Can select another free ftp service.

I'm have two issues:

1. End-points - If I'm using Passive mode, I'm need to allocate port range for this. Let's say 8000 to 8100. BUT, I'm have a option to allocate **only 20 ports** in the "End-points" interface.
2. I'm need to allocate at least one terabyte of storage in this server. How it's could be done with the machine?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of articles written on the subject. Whereas one of the most recent [is here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wats/archive/2013/12/13/setting-up-a-passive-ftp-server-in-windows-azure-vm.aspx).

Fr Virtual Machines, the limit of InputEndpoints is actually 150. Refer to the latest Azure limits [compilation here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/#vmlimits).

As for 1T storage - check the VM [sizes for Azure Virtual Mchines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn197896.aspx). Where A0 (the smallest) supports max 1 data disk of 1TB, and A4, A7 support 16 disks 1TB each (so total of 16TB per VM of size A4 or A7).

As for "built-in" endpoints - you can freely and surely remove them. Especially when you do not use them.

Comment: Only 25 ports is ludicrous! There are also "built-in" reserved ports (for rdp and power-shell) so only 23 ports left. This limit my concurrent level to only 23 simultaneously! I'm must say that this is less then I'm expected...